# How to add Admin rights to VB.net? Access Denied trying to replace Systems32\Hosts file w/ VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to replace my Hosts file, i can do it manually by overwriting it and now I'm trying to do it programmatically.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("\\174.0.0.253\startmenu$\ICONS\Host\dev\hosts", "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts", True)
```

i tried this -> http://williamfaulkner.co.uk/wordpress/2009/04/vbnet-run-as-administrator-impersonate-a-user-2008/

but to no avail still Access Denied.

Comment: In Visual Studio, have you gone into Windows Settings and set the privileges to "highest available"?  If not, I can walk through how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Projekt Properties
2. Application Tab
3. "View Windows Settings"-Button
4. Modify `requestedExecutionLevel`

Comment: Already tried these two no effect.
requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" 
requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable"

Comment: Did you try to run your program without Visual Studio? If this does work, you'll need to start VS as Admin.